# Generate code docs with SandCastle on TFS 2015 build server with solution of all doc projects

Tags: c#, sandcastle

I was trying to generate Sandcastle documentation on TFS 2015 build server in automated fashion. I have a single solution of all `shhbproj` for the libraries I need to generate document on. I have the documentation source to be the project files. However when I try execute it on the build server, it errors with

```
2>SHFB : warning BE0006: Unable to locate any documentation sources for 'F:\Builds\1\Portfolio\Project\MyProject.dll' (Configuration: Release Platform: AnyCPU) [F:\Builds\1\Portfolio\Project\MyProject.Docs.shfbproj]
```

Is there a way to run the Sandcastle doc generation independent of code compilation? Has anyone successfully tried it have the document project in a separate solution and was able to get it to build on the build server?

Things I have tried
1. Tried DLLs and XML comments as documentation source - No help.
2. Tried different build configuration - Debug/ Release

The link on [SandCastle site](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/ec822059-b179-4add-984d-485580050ffb.htm) doesn't talk of any special setting for it

Comment: Are you using XAML or scriptable (new) builds?

Comment: When the build is running, do you see the file 'F:\Builds\1\Portfolio\Project\MyProject.dll' on the build server? Are its XML files present as well?